# Japanese Double byte characters turn into squares PDF/SMARTFORMS

Tags: abap, truetype, sap-smart-forms

I'm trying to generate a PDF via a smartform with a japanese custom font added via TR SE73, which is a double byte font.

The Japanese's characters get displayed with squares in the PDF, I tried to use the ANDALE_J font it works, but with my custom font doesn't.

I would like to know if there is a way to fix this issue ?

[image]

Comment: You see them as squares because your pdf viewer does not recognize this font? At best put a sample document somewhere, so people can check whether they can see them correctly on their computers.

Comment: I tried with many pdf viewer (Microsoft Edge, AdobeReader, Google Viewer ...) in many computer, but it doesn't work !

Answer (score 1):

When you installed the Font in se73 did you check the checkbox which says do not insert this font in PDF? if yes then go ahead and reinstall it by not checking it.

If this method dint work then please drag and drop your font file to the font folder in control panel of your computer since Adobe checks the font from this folder not from the application server of SAP.[image]

Comment: Embedding a font in a PDF file will make it really huge, especially a Japanese font.

Comment: I understand! Correct me if am wrong, Installing any font in the computer rather than embedding it into a PDF file is fine i believe.

Comment: Yes, correct. But it's worth trying your solution of course. Moreover, maybe SAP does "font subsetting" instead of "font embedding", the difference being that subsetting only stores the characters used in the PDF file, so its size will be not so big.

Comment: Thanks @SandraRossi for explaining me this never knew SAP does "font subsetting". lets see if installing font helps! Hamza let us know if anything works out else lets change our thinking process!

Comment: Hello @AmNoOne, thanks for your reply, this is what i did in the first time, it doesn't work. I guess this is not the problem. I doubt the problem is the double byte font itself however it works normally on windows.